# date validation with time using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

How to validate '12/3/13 12:00:00 AM' also '12/29/13 12:00:00 AM'

i tried

```
"^(?:0[1-9]|1[12])/(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01])/[0-9]{4}\s(?:0[0-9]|1[1-2]):(?:[0-5][0-9]):  (?:[0-5][0-9])\s(?:AM|PM)$"
```

but not working

Comment: I would suggest doing a `DateTime.ParseExact`, then checking the date you get back.

Comment: Can't you use DateTime.TryParse method?

Comment: What about leap second? See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply use `DateTime.TryParse` and check if the conversion succeeded.

```
string date = "12/3/13 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse(date,dt))
    // do something
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the dates to be in that exact format,You should use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with these patterns

```
d/M/yy h:mm:ss tt
M/d/yy h:mm:ss tt
```